# Planar embeddings of planar graph

Tags: graphs, polynomial-time, planar-graphs

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a *planar* graph, only specified by its set of vertices and edges. Suppose $|V|=n$. According to [Fary's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A1ry%27s_theorem), there exists a *planar embedding* of $G$ with straight line segments. Then this embedding can be represented by a set of points in the plane (each $v\in V$ is represented by a unique point $p_v$ and there is a line segment between $p_u$ and $p_v$ iff $(u,v)\in E$)

Questions :

1. Is it possible to find this set of points in **polynomial time** (i.e. $n^{O(1)}$) ?
2. What if we force the points to have integer coordinates ?
3. Can we force the maximum (euclidian) distance between any two points to be $n^{O(1)}$ ?

Such statements could be very useful for proving lower bounds for some geometrical problems

Comment: All three of your questions are answered in the page you link.

Comment: I'm not sure, in this article they never mention the complexity of computing this planar embedding in polynomial time. My questions are not about existence but time complexity

Comment: In 'Related Results' they do mention being able to solve in linear time for a particular case.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting directly from the Wikipedia article linked in the question:

> De Fraysseix, Pach and Pollack showed how to find in linear time a straight-line drawing in a grid with dimensions linear in the size of the graph

As I commented earlier, this answers all three questions.